# Stripping everything but alphanumeric chars from a string in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was trying to get rid of all non-alphanumeric characters from a column in my dataframe and couldn't find a solution till I came across regex. Can someone explain to me why the first line of code didn't work but the second did? I looked at the documentation (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#) and followed what I saw.

Heres the first line of code with output:

```
teams_df['Team'] = (teams_df['Team'].astype('string')
                    .str.replace('\W', '', regex=False)
                   )
```

[image]

Heres the line of code/output that worked:

```
teams_df['Team'] = (teams_df['Team'].astype('string')
                    .str.replace(r'\W', '', regex=True)
                   )
```

[image]

I'd prefer to use the first line of code but it didnt work.

Comment: Please add your code as text, not as images or links to images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str.replace('\W', '', regex=False)` would try to use `'\W'` as an escape sequence (which is invalid). Even with `r'\W'` and `regex=False`, it would only replace literal occurrences of `\W` like in the string `r'TUV\WXY'`.

Thus only the combinations of `r'\W'` and `regex=True` makes sense to remove the non-alphanumeric characters:

```
str.replace(r'\W', '', regex=True)
```

Note that if you don't want to use a regex, you could go with [`str.strip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and a list of the characters to remove:

```
str.strip('*+')
```